# How to save a list of all the installed packages in Emacs 24?

Tags: emacs, emacs24, dot-emacs, emacs-prelude

I am using prelude as a base Emacs configuration.
I have installed lots of packages from the package manager, and I want to use my settings on another machine.

I don't want to carry the installed packages and also I don't want to create a list manually.

What is the way of saving a list all the installed packages into prelude-package.el or any other file so that when I take this configuration to my other machine, they automatically get installed there on first use?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can get a list of currently installed packages (excluding built in packages) from the variable `package-activated-list`.  To automatically install them on startup, see this question: [how to automatically install emacs packages by specifying a list of package names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092322/how-to-automatically-install-emacs-packages-by-specifying-a-list-of-package-name)

More specifically, if you do <kbd>C-h v package-activated-list</kbd>, copy the value shown, and insert it as the value of `prelude-packages`, emacs will automatically ensure those packages are installed on start up.

Comment: It is worth noting, the package-activated list is not updated by removing packages, but seems only on restart.

Answer (score 17):

The canonical method is the best (described by ataylor). Here is a more clumsy method.

<kbd>M-x list-packages</kbd>. <kbd>C-s installed</kbd> till you find the first row of installed package. Start selecting with <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>. Go down till you reach built-in packages. Copy with <kbd>M-w</kbd>. <kbd>C-x b</kbd> for new buffer. Paste with <kbd>C-y</kbd>.<kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> to save file.

The only advantage that I see is this is a tad more descriptive — it shows a short description of your packages; which is useful when you install some packages and forget about them.

Comment: Yes - I like that this adds a bit more description than the `package-activated-list`

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned at [how to automatically install emacs packages by specifying a list of package names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092322/how-to-automatically-install-emacs-packages-by-specifying-a-list-of-package-name), it would be better to also record the version of the package you need. In order to do so, you can use the following function:

```
(defun list-packages-and-versions ()
  "Returns a list of all installed packages and their versions"
  (mapcar
   (lambda (pkg)
     `(,pkg ,(package-desc-version
                (cadr (assq pkg package-alist)))))
   package-activated-list))
```

That will give you a list of `(NAME VERSION)` pairs. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a way to install a specific version of a package. It seems `package.el` always grabs the latest available. What I'm doing now is:

```
(defun install-packages-with-specific-versions (package-version-list)
  "Install the packages in the given list with specific versions.
PACKAGE-VERSION-LIST should be a list of (NAME VERSION) lists,
where NAME is a symbol identifying the package and VERSION is
the minimum version to install."
  (package-download-transaction
   (package-compute-transaction () package-version-list)))
```

I've written a longer function to install packages matching the exact version number, but it fails because `package.el` by default only retrieves the latest versions available for each package. [gist](https://gist.github.com/felipeochoa/1f1512dba8fe24601bc1e75b7af1e2ee)

Answer (score 1):

As described above, using emacs normal mode. Here another the evil-mode way of doing it:

M-x list-packages; /installed (they will be highlighted); v (for visual-mode); j (to select them); y (to copy them); open a new buffer and paste them.